# Does the product Singing and Dancing automatically remove email addresses which bounce back?

Tags: plone

If I add a csv with 5000 of my collected emails to Singing & Dancing, will the false emails be removed automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wrong and it is possible as per the comment below.  It would still be great if you would [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/singing-dancing/+filebug) regarding the lack of docs for this hidden feature.

Comment: This functionality does exist in S&D, though it is not yet documented:

Get the mailprocess package from PyPI [1], look at the example
configuration. You need to configure mailprocess to send the list of
bouncing email addresses to '/@@dancing.utils/handle_bounce'.

(Thanks to Daniel Nouri)